# Hybrid App Best Practices?

Tags: android, ios, git, cordova, mobile

I already have a running prototype of my iOS app build using Apache Cordova, and I'm planning on using the same codebase for Android.

Should I fork the iOS repository and start customizing Android?

or

Should I keep Android related changes as a separate branch of the same repository?

What's are some of the best practices that are followed, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to re-use part of the code base, you could just add a directory for the Android specific code in your `master` branch.

If you'd rather have components, you could put the common code base in its own repo, produce a library (eg: a maven package that you would publish on an internal maven repo), and have an iOS repo and an Android repo, both of which would reference this library.

However, unless you have a very large codebase (or unless you don't plan to make modifications in this common codebase), I wouldn't recommend the library-approach, since it can become a pain to add and test a minor patch in the common code base.

Regarding the approaches you proposed:

- a fork and a separate branch are more or less the same anyway (instead of having a branch `android`, you would have a branch `fork/master`)
- With an `android` and an `iOS` branches, changing the common codebase would require an extra merge that you wouldn't need with a single branch. And you have the risk of a desynchronisation of this common code base between your branches if you don't have a strict workflow

Comment: In my opinion based on the current climate today, I think it is essential that you have only one repository which is your root project folder. Any platform specific implementations should be done in the merge folder. I do not think it is wise to version control platform repos as it defeats the entire purpose. The aim is to have one repo with all platform specifics done via the config.xml and mege/hooks folders. This way whenever you add a platform with codova platform add command, the built platform will automatically get its configures stuff